# Changing form select field with a link clicked on a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a services page that links to an appointment page with a form and I would like the service selected to change in the dropdown to the correct service chosen.

The only solution to a similar question I could find was this answer below. However it does not appear to work when the form is on a separate page. When I copied the form onto the same page and use an anchor to the bottom of the page it will change the field however when using the link to the other page it does not. I am assuming this is due to the fact that it is on another page however I cannot locate much in regards to this situation.

I have included copies from my code of this, I believe I have included the relevant snippets from each section.

[Change dropdown option with jQuery/Javascript on link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737479/change-dropdown-option-with-jquery-javascript-on-link-click)

---

Declaring Scripts On Both Pages Head:

```html
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"> </script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>     
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Code From HTML Link on Service Page:

```html
<a href="BookAppointment.html" data-select="Bronze">
```

Code From JS:

```js
var $select = $('#package');
$('a[href="BookAppointment.html"]').click(function () {
    $select.val( $(this).data('select') );
});
```

Code From Appointment Form (More Options Not listed):

```html
<select name="package" id="package" >         
    <option value="Exterior Wash">Exterior Wash</option>
    <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
    <!-- more options -->
</select>
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: What technologie are using on server side?

Comment: Currently just running local testing, have not uploaded to server as of yet

Comment: So it would be rather evaluting your situation when you will be upgrading to real server app since there is no way to way to let *html* pages communicate together.
Your need could only be fulfilled with regard to the underlying technology through request parameters.

Comment: Sorry I am confused with what you are referring to with the server app. Would this be something provided by my hosting company or would it be something I upload it to the server myself.

Comment: No, what you are now trying by hand is writing a simple client side application right? *Just simple pages with JS and CSS inside*.
In order to achieve your need, the *data* attribute should be forwarded as a request parameter and processed by yout backend stuff.
This can be done through simple html code, though if this is fair enough for you. (I will provide an answer)

Comment: I honestly thought it had to be done through JavaScript/Jquery as this is the first time I have attempted to update a page based on links clicked on separate a URL. If there is a simple HTML solution I would prefer that as I have been going crazy trying to figure this out (now realizing why there isn't much information about doing this in JavaScript available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code work if you embed all elements in the same page, especially the `<select>` element, because your JS code is executed within the page scope. Thus you are able to change the select value when you hit the `a` href element.

In order to have your `data-select` value availble in the *BookAppointment.html* page, its value should be frowarded to that page.
So to sum up, when you hit the `a` href element from *services.html* page, the `data-select` value is processed via JavaScript and encapsulated as a **query parameter** then redirected to *BookAppointment.html* page.

- Now let's assume your *services.html* page is as follows (*Note the new service-script.js*):

```html
<head>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"> </script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>     
  <script src="service-script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <a href="BookAppointment.html" data-select="Bronze">
</body>
```

- Inside the *service-script.js* file you will be catching user click event on the `a` href and then retrieving the *data-select* value (just as you were doing before). New part is to introduce that value in the html reference you will be redirecting to:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href="BookAppointment.html"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data =  $(this).data('select');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?selectParam=' + escape(data);
  });
});
```

- Now you have to move your `<select>` block to *BookAppointment.html* page (*Note the new book-appointment-script.js*):

```html
<head>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"> </script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>     
  <script src="book-appointment-script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <select name="package" id="package" >         
    <option value="Exterior Wash">Exterior Wash</option>
    <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
    <!-- more options -->
  </select>
</body>
```

- In the *book-appointment-script.js* file you will be catching the ***selectParam*** query parameter and updating the select option based on it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var selectData = unescape(window.location.search.substring(1).split('=')[1]);
  var $select = $('#package');
  $select.val( selectData );
});
```

*You may need to escape and unescape html special characters, as this is just a straightforward example*.

Comment: I have attempted the changes as listed however now when loading the Bookappointment.html from any of the services or even the menu the select field is blank with no Option Selected.

Comment: I have updated my answer, sorry for misleading you.
I have updated the first JS body to be wrapped inside a `$(document).ready()` function and added snippet to prevent default href redirection.
Alson fixed the redirection URL in the second script and added escape/unescape statements as the first version would work for your second parameter *Exterior Wash*.

Comment: You my friend, I could kiss - That solved it - Thanks so much for the help and the explanation as well. I am still super new to JavaScript / JQuery and I don't even want to think about how long it would have taken to figure that out myself.

Comment: You are always welcome buddy :)
I would appreciate an upvote to make the response eligible for future readers ;)

Comment: I tried but I still haven't gotten the 15 reputation to do so :( - I selected it and will up-vote it asap