# Decode URL Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, url, escaping

I have the following code and escape seems not to be working.
I've tried replace but can't make it working.

The 'data' is being forward from another page and have parameters with 2 words eg:"full loaded", " just there"...

any help with be greatfuly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  var selectData = unescape(document.location.search.substring(1).split('=')[1]);
  var $select = $('#eventsList');
  $select.val( selectData );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href="http://pt.example.org/"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data =  $(this).data('select');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?selectParam=' + escape(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Side note: `this.href` is the same of `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 0):

When escaping URL GET parameters, you want to use encodeURIComponent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href="http://pt.example.org/"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data =  $(this).data('select');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?selectParam=' + encodeURIComponent(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I've tried it before but it does not work. Not sure why but can't make it to work. I should mention this code is to do something like the case shown on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104137/changing-form-select-field-with-a-link-clicked-on-a-different-page. I can select the form field correctly but the URL shows as mentioned. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled a bit with this, but found out that it only works with `href*`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*="http://pt.example.org/"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data =  $(this).data('select');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?selectParam=' + escape(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" href="http://pt.example.org/">pt.example.org</a>
```

---

The snippet won't work because `pt.example.org` doesn't exist, try it with an existent domain.

Comment: Pedro Lobito thank you for your answer your changes work on chrome, however unfortunately, I still have "/?selectParam=MUSTANG%202016 " showing on chrome and ie.

Comment: Try using `document.location`

Comment: maybe the problem is on this part of the code???"$(document).ready(function () {
  var selectData = unescape(document.location.search.substring(1).split('=')[1]);
  var $select = $('#eventsList');
  $select.val( selectData );
});"

Comment: Sorry I still kinda new around here. Code added to question. Apologies. Thank you for your help.

Comment: change this `var $select = $('#eventsList');
  $select.val( selectData );`  to this `var select = $('#eventsList');
  select.val( selectData );`